# Monad type signature example

Tags: haskell, monads, type-signature

The type signature of (+) is:

```
    (+) :: Num a => a -> a -> a
```

I can see this in:

```
    + 4 5
```

Resulting in 9.  + takes 4 and returns a function of roughly:

```
    (4 + a) -> a
```

...which then takes 5 and evaluates to 9.  Basically, two things in, one thing out.  I don't see how this works using the bind operator's type signature.  To me, in practice, it always looks like one in, one out.

Could someone please walk me through a simple example using a Maybe monad the way I've done above for (+) ?  Hopefully, this will be generally useful to Haskell newbie's like me!

Comment: What do you mean by this? Please be more specific.

Comment: How is the `(+)` example related to monads? The monadic bind operator is `>>=`, and is unrelated to the application `(+) 4 9` or the partial application `(+) 4`.

Comment: @chi They are related in that both `(+)` and `(>>=)` are binary operators, but that's pretty much it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the type signature of bind:

```
(>>=)
    :: Monad m
    => m a         -- Left argument
    -> (a -> m b)  -- Right argument
    -> m b
```

Here is an example of a bind with two arguments:

```
Just 1 >>= (\n -> Just (n + 1))
^^^^^^     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Arg #1     Arg #2
```

.. and it evaluates to `Just 2`

Comment: Oh hi, Gabriel!  I've been reading your site/blog.  Mostly over my head, but very interesting nonetheless.  So, m a is Just 1.  Got that.  Then, the value from Just 1 gets shoved into the lambda function.  That value would be a in the right argument, right?  One gets added to the value.  How does a monad pop out without using return?  Oh, the lambda is still an argument to the monad, so it does it 'automagically'?

Comment: For `Maybe`, `return` is the same as `Just`. The function `\n -> return (n + 1)` does the exact same thing as the lambda function in Gabriel's example but it would work for any monad.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for a ton of very helpul information.  Many things have clicked in the last few hours.  Hard choice, but I think this answer most directly responded to the question, and did so in the simplest way, which was what I needed to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone please walk me through a simple example using the `Maybe` monad the way I've done above for `(+)`?

`(>>=)` combines a monadic action with a function that returns a monadic action:

```
(       >>=            ) :: Maybe Int -> (Int -> Maybe Bool) -> Maybe Bool
(Just 1 >>=            ) ::              (Int -> Maybe Bool) -> Maybe Bool
(Just 1 >>= Just . even) ::                                     Maybe Bool
```

Exactly as with `(+)`, two things go in (a monadic action and a function returning a monadic action) and one thing comes out (a monadic action).

> To me, in practice, it always looks like one in, one out.

Note that Haskell monads are unrelated to APL monads which are indeed unary functions.

Answer (score 0):

The thing that confuses people a lot when they see the `>>=` type signature, is that it looks lop-sided

If you take `+` you get a signature like this:

```
(+) :: Num a 
    => a  -- 1st arg
    -> a  -- 2nd arg
    -> a  -- return-type
```

If you take `.` you get this:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -- 1st arg, a function from b to c
    -> (a -> b) -- 2nd arg, a function from a to b
    ->  a -> c  -- return-type, a function from a to c
```

Nothing so far is scary

Now take a look at `>>=`

```
(>>=) :: Monad m
      =>       m a  -- 1st arg, a monad a
      -> (a -> m b) -- 2nd arg, a function from a to a monad b
      ->       m b  -- return-type, a monad b
```

The 1st argument doesn't match the 2nd one, but that's okay, and I'm gonna show why.

So let's say you have a the following two functions:

```
f :: Monad m => a -> m a -- we just need the type signatures
g :: Monad m => a -> m a
```

We then do the following:

```
\a -> f a >>= \b -> g b
```

What's the type of `f a`? it's `m a`, what's the type of `g b`? it's `m b`

So basically what I did was this:

```
function: \a -> f a >>= \b -> g b
types   :  a -> m a      b -> m b
```

What was the type of `>>=`'s arguments? Look again:

```
function: \a -> f a >>= \b -> g b
types   :  a -> m a      b -> m b
>>=-args:       m a  -> (b -> m b)
```

So in essence what we've done here, is by adding a lambda to the expression, we've *completed* the "missing" type information that made the signature "lop-sided"

```
\n -> (Just n >>= (\m -> Just (m + 1))) -- added extra () for highlighting
```

or put differently:

```
fn a = Just a >>= (\m -> Just (m + 1))
fn 3 -- returns Just 4
```

Essentially what I just did, was create a function `fn` with the signature `a -> m a`... Exactly the same as `f` and `g`. So what `>>=` is, is a way to compose monadic funcions. Just like how `.` is a way to compose *normal* functions.

Watch [[Don't fear the Monad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhuHCtR3xq8)] which was the inspiration for this answer, and ultimately what made me somewhat understand why it looks the way it does.

Comment: Thank you!  This is going to take me a couple tries to digest, but I will be back.  Thanks for connecting it to (.) -- that helps.  For now, it just occurred to me that the function argument is always a lambda in examples.  Is it so inside an actual monad?  In this example, (from LYAHfGG), or general chaining, or just in general I guess, where is the function argument (a -> m b)?  It looks like one value in, one value out.  ghci> return (0,0) >>= landLeft 1 >>= banana >>= landRight 1  I think that's the sticking point for me.

Comment: @curieux It might help to put all the parentheses in: `(((return (0,0)) >>= (landLeft 1)) >>= banana) >>= (landRight 1)`. `(>>=)` is just a normal function that happens to be infix operator, there's nothing really magical about it. Its first argument is on the left and its second argument is on the right. You can make a non-operator synonym for it: `bind x f = x >>= f` and then you could rewrite this example as `bind (bind (bind (return (0,0)) (landLeft 1)) banana) (landRight 1)`